# IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to run the code below, but I get the following error message:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-43d3d8bbcec7> in <module>
      7     return data_bc
      8 
----> 9 st_bc(data = df.to_numpy())

<ipython-input-105-43d3d8bbcec7> in st_bc(data)
      4     data_bc = np.zeros_like(data)
      5     for column in list(data):
----> 6         data_bc[column], lam = scipy.stats.boxcox(data[column])
      7     return data_bc
      8 

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

If you can elaborate on how to make it work I would really pretiate it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')).astype('float64')

def st_bc(data):
   data_bc = np.zeros_like(data)
   for column in list(data):
           data_bc[column], lam = stats.boxcox(data[column])
   return data_bc

st_bc(data = df.to_numpy())
```

Comment: please say what will be your ideal output. what do you want to do?

Comment: Why are you initializing a dataframe from an array, only to unpack it back to an array?

Answer (score 1):

- `IndexError` was caused by using floats instead of ints to index the arrays.

  - Arrays can't be indexed by an array as `data_bc[column]` or `data[column]`
  - Use enumerate to properly index the arrays.
  - The data can have floats, but floats can't be used to index the arrays.
- There's no reason to convert an array to a dataframe and back to an array.
- I've added, returning a list of the `lambda` parameters from `boxcox`.
- Finally, if you're thinking of the array like a dataframe, then `boxcox` is being applied across the rows, not the columns.

  - The array needs to be transposed for `boxcox` to be applied across the columns
  - The output of `st_bc` will now correspond to applying `boxcox` to the dataframe as shown in the second part of this solution.

```py
import numpy
import scipy


def st_bc(data):
    data = data.T
    data_bc = np.zeros_like(data)

    lams = list()
    for i, column in enumerate(list(data)):
        data_bc[i], lam = scipy.stats.boxcox(data[i])
        lams.append(lam)
    return data_bc.T, lams


np.random.seed(1)
data = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(100, 4)).astype('float64')
bc_array, lams_list = st_bc(data)

# print(data[:5, :])
array([[38., 13., 73., 10.],
       [76.,  6., 80., 65.],
       [17.,  2., 77., 72.],
       [ 7., 26., 51., 21.],
       [19., 85., 12., 29.]])

# print(bc_array[:5, :])
array([[13.5733518 ,  7.08438022, 25.44409142,  7.32995319],
       [21.63925203,  3.54921753, 27.16422209, 41.78155162],
       [ 7.64782254,  0.88958263, 26.43324502, 45.75934397],
       [ 3.75096568, 12.33694984, 19.64519548, 14.97979832],
       [ 8.30355027, 29.84841173,  6.46011688, 20.18489135]])

# print(lams_list)
[0.6140869325642362,
 0.6923022809975391,
 0.6763741407884145,
 0.8662712497789992]
```

## Using a dataframe

- Apply `boxcox` to the entire dataframe
- See that the result corresponds to the output of `st_bc`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

# apply boxcox
(a_bc, a_lam), (b_bc, b_lam), (c_bc, c_lam), (d_bc, d_lam) = df.apply(scipy.stats.boxcox)

# put the boxcox result in a dataframe
bc_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a_bc, 'b': b_bc, 'c': c_bc, 'd': d_bc})

# dispaly(bc_df.head())
           a          b          c          d
0  13.573352   7.084380  25.444091   7.329953
1  21.639252   3.549218  27.164222  41.781552
2   7.647823   0.889583  26.433245  45.759344
3   3.750966  12.336950  19.645195  14.979798
4   8.303550  29.848412   6.460117  20.184891

# print(a_lam, b_lam, c_lam, d_lam)
0.6140869325642362 0.6923022809975391 0.6763741407884145 0.8662712497789992
```

Comment: @MarioArend They're float, but they are all `.0` so I guess that's what numpy is doing. Or do you mean `13.5733518`?

Comment: @MarioArend that was what was returned when `data` type was `int`. Before adding `.astype('float64')`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [92]: data = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                                           
In [93]: data                                                                                        
Out[93]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Look at what you get when you iterate on a 2d array:

```
In [94]: for col in list(data): 
    ...:     print(col) 
    ...:                                                                                             
[0 1 2 3]
[4 5 6 7]
[ 8  9 10 11]
```

You get rows of the array.  It doesn't make sense to index with that row, `data[col]`.  You can use the `col` value directly.  If you do need an index, use `enumerate` or `for i in range(...):`

This is a basic Python iteration issue.  Even when using `pandas` and `numpy` it pays to learn the underlying language :)